# Flutter - Update parent state from child

Tags: dart, flutter, state

I'm not able to update the parent state from a child. The child widget has a callback named 'onDragEnd' which is called once the drag and drop operation on a grid cell is finished. At this time the parent (the grid) should rebuild UI according to the items new sort, but nothing happens. If I set a breakpoint before the 'setState()' the 'elems' property contains the correct items with right sorting. Even if I replace the entire list, UI is not updating. Any suggestions? What am I missing?

```
class _CustomGridState extends State<CustomGrid> { 

    List<Pack> elems;

    _CustomGridState(this.elems);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: this
                  .elems
                  .map((pack) => PackFingernail(pack: pack,

                       onDragEnd: (Pack source, Pack target) {

                            var sourceIndex = this.elems.indexWhere((p) => p.id == source.id);
                            var targetIndex = this.elems.indexWhere((p) => p.id == target.id);

                            this.elems.removeAt(sourceIndex);
                            this.elems.insert(targetIndex, source);

                            setState(() {}); // Not working <-----
                       })

                   ).toList()
               );
   }
 }
```

Comment: PackFingernail is stateful widget?

Comment: Yes, it's a stateful widget, and it manages its internal state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a key for your `PackFingernail`

```
// constructor    
PackFingernail(..., {Key key}): super(key:key)

// in gridview
.map((pack) => PackFingernail(pack: pack,
 onDragEnd: (Pack source, Pack target) {
    ...
 },
 key: Key(pack.id.toString()))
).toList()
```

`Key` can help to rebuild the `GridView`